# ES6: Access two different scopes (class-global and object-local) in the same function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

This is kind of hard to explain. Please excuse the farfetched example.

**I want to access two different scopes (class-global and object-local) in the same function. Said function is an object-method.**

I'm using `babel-preset-react-native`, which should be ES6 (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html).

Given the following example-class:

```js
class Logic {

  constructor() {
    this.keys = ['Red Key', 'Blue Key'];
  }

  hasKey = (searchKey) => {
    return this.keys.includes(searchKey);
  }

  allowedToEnter = {
    redHouse: () => {
      // some logic
      return true;
    },
    // ...
  };

  houses = [
    {
      name: 'Red House',
      isAccessible: () => {
        return this.hasKey('Red Key');
      },
      shouldAccess__Global: () => {
        return /* wrong scope */this.isAccessible() && this.allowedToEnter.redHouse();
      },
      shouldAccess__Local: function () {
        return this.isAccessible() && /* wrong scope */this.allowedToEnter.redHouse();
      },
    },
    // ...
  ];
}

let logic = new Logic();
console.log(logic.houses[0].shouldAccess__Global());
// returns: isAccessible is not a function
console.log(logic.houses[0].shouldAccess__Local());
// returns: Cannot read property 'redHouse' of undefined
```

Defining an arrow function binds the class-scope to `this`. Using the classic function syntax, it binds `this` to the scope of it's "owner", the house-object inside the array. I understand that, in both cases, this is correct behavior.

**Is there an elegant way to write the `shouldAccess` method, giving access to both scopes?**

A possible solution I came up with is the following:

```js
shouldAccess__withHelper: function () {
  return this.isAccessible() && this.helper().allowedToEnter.redHouse();
},
helper: () => {
  return this;
},
```

This is not elegant thought. I have a large amount of house-objects in my array. Giving each object a helper function sucks.

I know that the whole data-structure is a bit convoluted and not ideal. I'm not asking for advice on how to structured my code better.
I'm working with a large amount of logic that's in the given structure and refactoring everything would be a huge pain.

Comment: Can't you just declare a variable outside the function like... `var outerThis = this`

Comment: Based on the shown code this should work: `var globalThis = this; class Logic { ...  shouldAccess: function () { this.isAccessible() && globalThis.allowedToEnter.redHouse() }` ?

Comment: ty, but both suggestions don't work. `shouldAccess__Local` doesn't have access to the class-scope at all, so defining `outerThis = this` in the class constructor doesn't help. `var globalThis = this;` outside the class doesn't give me access class functions.

Comment: In JS OOP, `this` should refer to class instance, as a rule of thumb. This problem indicates that class design went wrong. That you can wrap everything with `class` keyword doesn't mean that this should be done. Why would there be a `Logic` thing? This doesn't sound like proper entity for a class. That it doesn't use state and thus doesn't benefit from instantiation suggests that it shouldn't be a class.

Comment: You are right, I pretty much wrapped legacy code in a class. But it does indeed subscribe to a state, I just cut that out in the example for simplification. You make a good point though, maybe class isn't the right approach.

Comment: @estus looking forward to it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Logic` doesn't seem to be a proper entity for a class. While houses seem to be proper entities, but they aren't classes.

In JS OOP, `this` usually refers to class instance, as a rule of thumb. Рouses classes would make it easier to handle house-logic relationship, and 'logic' instance is provided via dependency injection:

```
class AbstractHouse {
  constructor(logic, name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.logic = logic;
  }
}

class RedHouse extends AbstractHouse {
  constructor(logic, name = 'Red House') {
    super(logic, name);
  }

  shouldAccess() {
    return this.isAccessible() && this.logic.allowedToEnter.redHouse()
  }
}

class Logic {
  ...
  houses = [new RedHouse(this)];
}
```

The fact that base class should be extended for every house type to list `redHouse` method name explicitly depending on house type suggests that it's not a perfect relationship and could be improved to be more flexible. It's also not known how many house types are there and whether it's a good idea to have a class for each type.

Even without actual class, houses can follow certain interface to expose 'logic' instance to their methods:

```
  houses = [
    {
      logic: this, // same as dependency injection in house constructor
      name: 'Red House',
      shouldAccess() {
        return this.isAccessible() && this.logic.allowedToEnter.redHouse()
      }
      ...
    }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Structuring my thoughts and asking a question helped me come up with another possible solution.

Defining `shouldAccess` like the following ...

```js
shouldAccess__passLogic: function (logic) {
  return this.isAccessible() && logic.allowedToEnter.redHouse();
},
```

... and passing the class instance to that function on function-call (`console.log(logic.houses[0].shouldAccess__Local(logic));`) does fix the problem. Not very beautiful, but should at least be easy to refactor.

I'm still open to other suggestions though!